# How do I get key name on this array loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

**I have 2 keys:**

> 1. content
> 2. media

**I then run this:**

```
$fields = get_post_meta($postId);
unset($fields['_edit_lock'], $fields['_edit_last'], $fields['_thumbnail_id']);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($fields as $i) {
    foreach($i as $key => $value) {
        echo '<li>'.$i.'->'.$value.'</li>';
    }       
}
```

**That gives me:**

> 1. Array-> 327
> 2. Array-> Custom test 1
> 3. Array-> Custom test 2

**What I'm looking for is:**

> 1. Media-> 327
> 2. Content-> Custom test 1
> 3. Content-> Custom test 2

Comment: provide input examples and your desired outputs, will be easier to help you

Comment: Replace `$i` with `$key` ?

Comment: @0stone0 nope, I've tried and it gives me "0->327
0->
Custom test 1

1->
Custom test 2

Comment: @ericmp I did, it's the lats bit on the question

Comment: Then please add a [mre] so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @0stone0 that's the only code I have, I did provide all the infos

Comment: @rob.m Then `foreach($fields as $keyName => $i) {` and `echo '<li>'.$keyName .'->'.$value.'</li>';`

Comment: Maybe you want the key of the outer loop - that of `$fields` ...? Hard to tell, when you don't provide _specific_ information what this variable actually contains.

Comment: @nice_dev I'm not sure what's the different, can you tell me please? Yet with your code I get the key names but not the values

Comment: @rob.m I had the exact same change to be made as the answer and it seems to work for you. Now I need the extra credit to guess correctly without an MVCE :D

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
foreach ((array) get_post_meta($postId) as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
    if (!in_array($arrayKey, array("_edit_lock", "_edit_last", "_thumbnail_id"))) {
        foreach ($arrayValue as $key => $value) {
            echo '<li>' . $arrayKey . '->' . $value . '</li>';
        }
    }
}
```

**If you are in a scenario like this:**
You have a array like this:

```
$fields = array(
    'media' => array(
        0 => '327',
    ),
    'content' => array(
        0 => 'Custom test 1',
        1 => 'Custom test 2',
    ),
    'link' => array(
        0 => 'Custom test 10',
        1 => 'Custom test 20',
        2 => 'Custom test 30',
        3 => 'Custom test 40',
    ),
    'embed' => array(
        0 => 'Custom test 100',
        1 => 'Custom test 200',
        2 => 'Custom test 300',
    ),
    '_edit_lock' => array(
        0 => '1667908749:1',
    ),
);
```

You just want these keys:

> media
>
> content
>
> LInk
>
> Embed

I need to output their values in sequence as per this example:

> media
>
> content
>
> link
>
> embed

New rows....

> media
>
> content
>
> link
>
> embed

You want to get something like this:

```
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 10
embed->Custom test 100
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 10
embed->Custom test 200
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 10
embed->Custom test 300
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 20
embed->Custom test 100
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 20
embed->Custom test 200
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 20
embed->Custom test 300
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 30
embed->Custom test 100
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 30
embed->Custom test 200
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 30
embed->Custom test 300
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 40
embed->Custom test 100
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 40
embed->Custom test 200
media->327
content->Custom test 1
link->Custom test 40
embed->Custom test 300
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 10
embed->Custom test 100
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 10
embed->Custom test 200
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 10
embed->Custom test 300
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 20
embed->Custom test 100
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 20
embed->Custom test 200
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 20
embed->Custom test 300
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 30
embed->Custom test 100
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 30
embed->Custom test 200
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 30
embed->Custom test 300
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 40
embed->Custom test 100
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 40
embed->Custom test 200
media->327
content->Custom test 2
link->Custom test 40
embed->Custom test 300
```

So do this:

```
echo '<ul>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields['media']); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($fields['content']); $j++) {
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($fields['link']); $k++) {
            for ($z = 0; $z < count($fields['embed']); $z++) {
                echo '<li>media->' . $fields['media'][$i] . '</li>';
                echo '<li>content->' . $fields['content'][$j] . '</li>';
                echo '<li>link->' . $fields['link'][$k] . '</li>';
                echo '<li>embed->' . $fields['embed'][$z] . '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: @rob.m sir, I've reviewed your next question and I have an answer for it. I'm changing this answer now. Please follow and I would appreciate if you give feedback.

Comment: thanks a lot, thing is you have a single array `$fields['media']` but where is field declared? They are 3 different arrays which should be merged before i guess. As it stands they are:        `$content = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'content'));`
       `$media = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'media'));`
       `$yt = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'youtube'));`

Comment: i've created a new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360719/how-do-i-get-key-name-on-this-array-loop