# How do I read an array key of an associative array?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is what I'm doing:

```
$content = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'content'));
$media = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'media'));
$yt = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'youtube'));
$max = max(count($content), count($media), count($yt));
$combined = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    if(isset($content[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "content", "value" => $content[$i]];
    }
    if(isset($media[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "media", "value" => $media[$i]];
    }
    if(isset($yt[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "youtube", "value" => $yt[$i]];
    }
}
foreach ($combined as $key => $val) {
    echo '<li>'.$val['value'].'</li>';
}
```

The result is:

```
Array
Array
Array
```

I'd expect:

```
media value
content value
youtube value
```

Comment: For future note, I would recommend writing a single, well-written question instead of creating [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74365997/how-to-merge-3-arrays-keeping-their-meta-key) [separate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362594/how-to-echo-alternated-arrays-keys-and-values) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360719/how-do-i-get-key-name-on-this-array-loop) [about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360398/how-to-skip-a-meta-key) (which are closed as "needs clarity"). You're likely to get relevant help faster with well-written questions.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones they are 2 totally different questions, they have completely different code and issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working with array of arrays because [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) returns by default an array, unless the 3rd parameter `$single` is true.

So try

```php
$content = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'content', true));
```

or actually just

```php
$content = get_post_meta($postId, 'content');
```

Answer (score -2):

You realise that

```
$content = array(get_post_meta($postId, 'content'));
```

creates `$content` as an array with a single value? (the value is whatever is returned by your `get_post_meta()` function)
(and similarly for `$media` and `$yt`)
Each of these three will always have one and only one element.

Looking at the code that follows this, I'm not sure if this is what you intended. `$max` will always be one, for example, and `$content[$i]` will always be the value returned by your `get_post_meta()` function - based on the result shown, presumably an array